# Power series difficulty

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

How would I find the region of convergence of the series of $\frac{1}{n^3}(\frac{z+1}{z-1})^n$. I thought about rewriting $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ as $\frac{2}{z-1}+1$ but I don't think that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Consider the linear fractional transformation $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ as mapping some regions onto the open disks centered at the origin, and work backwards from $\sum \frac{x^n}{n^3}$ to find the region of convergence for variable $z$.

Comment: That's not a power series, so it doesn't have a radius of convergence.

Comment: @Thomas: I read "region" of convergence in the problem statement.

Comment: Yeah, I either misread it or it was quickly edited. Still, it is not a power series :) @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $w = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$. Then you have a power series in $w$, centered at $0$. Find its radius of convergence, call that $R$. Then find which $z$ correspond to $\lvert w\rvert < R$. The map $z \mapsto \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ can be explicitly inverted.

Comment: There's a pretty obvious way to express $|z-(-1)|<|z-1|$, without inverting that transformation...

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I get that the series converges when $|\frac{z+1}{z-1}|<1$. How do I now check on the boundary of that ? Thanks

Comment: @user137090 $\sum \frac{1}{n^3}$ converges, so it converges everywhere on the boundary.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I'm confused. If I make the transformation, can I treat it as a power series?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but what if $R\neq 1$? (whistles)

Comment: @user137090 With the change of variables $w = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$, you get a power series in $w$. So you can apply everything you know about power series to that. Then you can translate it back to $z$ by the inverse change of variables. Note that the region of convergence for $z$ is not a disk, so you can't write the function as a power series $\sum c_n (z-a)^n$ with the same region of convergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer So from this what can I say when $|\frac{z+1}{z-1}|{\geq}1?$

Comment: @user137090 For $\left\lvert\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right\rvert = 1$, the series converges (absolutely) since $\sum \frac{1}{n^3} < \infty$. For $\left\lvert \frac{z+1}{z-1}\right\rvert > 1$, the terms of the series don't converge to $0$ (they grow exponentially in absolute value), so the series diverges then.